# Generate automatically a delta feed in OData

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata, webapi, delta

in odata (.net core) it is possible to generate delta results in a delta feedback,
like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/DeltaFeed_support.

As I see in the example, they create manually the delta response. This can occur in very large result a long-running task before it will be sent back to the client.

I wonder if there is possible, to get an automated way of doing this and how?

So I use entity framework for this.

I thought a little bit about it, but I don't see another change to implement a "log" table to hold every action on all entities, or I must use an event sourcing pattern. The second one was not a choice for already implemented solutions I think.

Maybe there exists another way for this?
Any Ideas?

Comment: It is Delta for period of time? Which database do you use?

Comment: I wann to alloe a Client to select data. The system must then result the results and give him delta token. Maybe the Client must tell him to deliver him a delta token. The Database is sql server